# Implement details of std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11

[This website](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/) teach us how to implement a simple std::tuple, but there are a piece of codes I do not understand

```
template <size_t k, class... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<
    k == 0, typename elem_type_holder<0, tuple<Ts...>>::type&>::type
get(tuple<Ts...>& t) {
  return t.tail;
}

template <size_t k, class T, class... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<
    k != 0, typename elem_type_holder<k, tuple<T, Ts...>>::type&>::type
get(tuple<T, Ts...>& t) {      
  //Why t could assign to different type?
  tuple<Ts...>& base = t;
  return get<k - 1>(base);
}
```

My question is

```
tuple<T, Ts...>
```

and

```
tuple<Ts...>
```

are different types, how could it work?

Edit : I think I found the answer, because

```
tuple<Ts...>
```

is base class of

```
tuple<T,Ts...>
```

Comment: Do you know how inheritance works?

Comment: In the second case `Ts...` type list can consist of `T, Ts...` so they can be the same type.

Comment: @VTT No, that would make `Ts...` an infinite list.

Comment: @meplomene yes, I know, my unfamiliar with variadic template blind my eye at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `tuple<T, Ts...>` inherits from `tuple<Ts...>`.